# Ruby array.flatten.each, action conditional on type

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with nested hashes and arrays.  I am trying to basically replace all the array/hash values (recursively) that are not an array or a hash themselves.  I have this mostly working, but I have a case where an array may contain both hashes and strings.  I am using two flatten statements do this:

```
v.flatten.each { |x| clear_hash(x) if x.is_a?(Hash) }
v.flatten.each { |y| y.replace(newVal) if x.is_a?(String) }
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this in one `flatten.each` as I assume this makes two full passes over the array.  I tried to do something like this:

```
v.flatten.each { |x| clear_hash(x) if x.is_a?(Hash) else x.replace(newVal) }
```

It does not seem that an else statement can be used here.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The `else` can be used if you structure it is `if...clear_hash()...else x.replace()` instead of trying to do it as a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `else` statement with an `if` only when it is not a trailing `if`. So you'd need something like this:

```
v.flatten.each { |x| if x.is_a?(Hash) then clear_hash(x) elsif x.is_a?(String) then x.replace(newVal) end }
```

Or for better readability you might want to spread it out onto multiple lines:

```
v.flatten.each do |x|
  if x.is_a?(Hash)
    clear_hash(x)
  elsif x.is_a?(String)
    x.replace(newVal)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  Multiple line is fine, I really meant so that I don't need to make two passes.

Comment: This would more idiomatically be written with a `case` expression instead of an `if`  expression: `case x when Hash then clear_hash(x) when String then x.replace(newVal) end`